# How to solve my error in redshiftsinkconnector

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-connect

I try to connect kafka and redshift in the redshiftsink connector.the connector is running and the task is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9hHr.png) failed .

Comment: Please add your error as text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

Your error - `Failed to deserialize data in topic ... to Avro`

So, if your data is not Avro, then change your `key.converter` and/or `value.converter` to the appropriate config. You need to consult your Producer code for the matching serializers.